# Doctrine 2 ClassMetadata with Custom Annotations

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection, doctrine-orm

I am trying to code the process of creating Zend_Form objects using Doctrine2 ClassMetadatas so that form generation for my client database application is easier.

I needed somewhere to store the element labels, descriptions, and etc. using custom phpdoc tags seemed a good idea. But it seems ClassMetadataInfo doesn't provide 'annotations' outside what it's expecting.

Thats sensible I guess, but im struggling to find a way to get it to parse the entire phpdoc block.

I've looked at using getReflectionClass() and parsing it myself, but id loose out on the great caching. The Doctrine2 parser works really well for what it does, but I can't make heads or tails of it!

Being able to use the phpdoc *short description* as an element label, and *long description* as the description would be rather handy for my form<>model friendships.

Anyone else pondered on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dotrine2 provides both an AnnotationDriver (which is used by the ORM) and an AnnotationReader (used by the driver and which provides more abstract method).

Take a look at the source

[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php)

[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php)

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone finds this answer: The latest version of Doctrine as of now includes a more advanced annotation reader, including caching mechanisms (which you probably want). Take a look at [the doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/common/2.1/en/reference/annotations.html) for some nice examples of usage.